# R Memory Management For Large Datasets

Tags: r, memory-management

I am quite new to R and I am currently working on a dataset (size: 2 GB size). I have stored this dataset in a workspace and whenever I load this dataset into R it consumes more than 90% main memory and hence it becomes difficult and highly time consuming to perform operations like filtering, processing and analyzing the data.

I am mainly using dplyr package to filter and form subsets out of the main dataset, as per dynamic user inputs, but it is taking a lot of time to fetch the data. I have also tried using bigmemory package. While it solves the memory consumption issues, it does not allow the dplyr package functions on big.matrix objects.

So can anyone please let me know how can I filter large datasets quickly with optimal memory consumption?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into data.table?

Comment: How exactly do you load the data?

Comment: @C.Braun No, I have not tried data.table. I will also try that. Thanks for suggesting!

Comment: @jaySf i have used for normal dataset: read.csv("filename.csv",header =T, sep ="|")
And for big matrix object:
read big.matrix ("filename.csv", header = T, sep ="|", type = "char", backingfile = "filename.bin", descriptorfile="filename.desc")

Comment: You could/should use `fread` instead of `read.csv` which is from the package `data.table`. It is also much faster in managing data. You could maybe also increase the memory size with `memory.limit()`

Comment: @C.Braun I am using data.table and it is working quite smoothly now. However when I am trying to load the subset details into dashboard using shiny, it is taking way too much time. Do you have any suggestions on this please?

Comment: I have got the correct function. It is renderDataTable(). Using this function I am able to render the data quickly on the dashboard. Thanks all for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used data.table and DT packages. Using data.table I created a data.table object that can be accessed and analysed quickly. And using renderDataTable function from DT package, I was able to render the table on Shiny dashboard quickly.
Thanks all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to truncate the table to the columns needed while downloading.

***Example***

```
sample1 <- read.csv("https://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-500000-rows.csv",
                    header=TRUE)

sample2 <- read.csv("https://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-500000-rows.csv",
                    header=TRUE)[, c(1, 3, 5)]
> object.size(sample1)
3272064 bytes
> object.size(sample2)
1073240 bytes
```

To know which to choose, consult the colnames using

```
var.names <- names(read.csv("https://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-500000-rows.csv",
                    header=TRUE))
> var.names
[1] "Eldon.Base.for.stackable.storage.shelf..platinum"
[2] "Muhammed.MacIntyre"                              
[3] "X3"                                              
[4] "X.213.25"                                        
[5] "X38.94"                                          
[6] "X35"                                             
[7] "Nunavut"                                         
[8] "Storage...Organization"                          
[9] "X0.8"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have to consider all 20 columns as they are equally important.

Answer (score 0):

I have used data.table and DT packages. Using data.table I created a data.table object which is fast to access and analyse. And using DT package, I used the renderDataTable function to get the details quickly on Shiny dashboard.